# DOM inspection of arbitrary webpages

Tags: javascript, dom, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to create a web application that would allow users to view arbitrary webpages and graphically select specific HTML elements from those pages. Essentially, I'm asking for basic Firebug-like DOM inspection capabilities, but within a web app.

My first thought was just to create an iframe to load the third-party webpages, and to inspect their DOM with JavaScript, but I realized I'd run into problems due to the same-origin policy.

Is there a way to do what I want to do, or is this impossible for security reasons? If I can't get what I want with a native web-app, what's the least I'd have to compromise to get the required functionality? Would asking the user to add a bookmarklet (a la Firebug Lite) be enough, or would I have to build a full-blown browser plugin?

Comment: You can scrape the page server side, return the data, and then render it.  That alleviates the origin policy....   it essentially, loads the page into a string, and retrieves the string, then you re-render the string to the page.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I've tried something like this in the past and run into issues ... if a third-party page from abc.com makes any references to resources from that domain, then when I serve up the page verbatim from my server, won't the references be broken?

Comment: yup.  Thats where things start to get a bit more tricky.  You are attempting to do something which will have a lot of RED FLAGS.  You are doing something built into browsers or an extension of sorts.  You have to understand what would and would not be allowed.  NOW, you could, if you wanted to temporarily store those datasets in a folder or something on yourserver, a server doing a recursive scrape of information.  That would work, but really, how much do you want your servers to work and how much is going to need to be stored to accomplish your end goals. You might want to do more research.